# Why this less declaration doesn't work?

Tags: css, web, less, lint

Variables can't contain a whole CSS rule declaration?

```
@teko: {
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif
};

@title: @teko;

.test{
  @teko
};
```

Comment: I just tidied up your code for readability - and also wrapped it in a code block, rather than in-line code - please check to make sure that in spacing it out I haven't somehow created errors. Incidentally, in CSS the semi-colons (`;`) should follow the property-values and be *inside* of the curly-braces, and not following them.

Comment: See [Passing Rulesets to Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) for the proper syntax. Though mixins (like suggested in the answers below) would be a better fit in this case (Unnamed rulesets are typically useful only when you need to pass blocks as parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can mix ([mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature)) class selctors and id selctors in LESS. here is what you want to do,

```
@fontFamily: Teko, sans-serif;

@teko: @fontFamily;

.test {
 font-family: @teko;  
}
```

also you can go through the following [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-comprehensive-introduction-to-less-mixins/) to learn more about mixins

Comment: What if there is more than one font, can i use de same @fontfamily but different declaration(different fonts)?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but mixins can.

```
.my-mixin {
  color: black;
  padding: 2px;
}
.class {
  .my-mixin;
}
```

outputs

```
.class {
  color: black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature